# Monkey patching and callback error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching

I'm using two gems in an Rails 4 application: [acts_as_tenant](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant) and [simple_hashtags](https://github.com/ralovely/simple_hashtag).

If a hashtag exist on one tenant, it won't be resaved for the other tenant. So I want to override the [find_or_create_by_name](https://github.com/ralovely/simple_hashtag/blob/master/lib/simple_hashtag/hashtag.rb#L17) and find_by_name methods.
For that, I also need to override the [parsed_hashtags method](https://github.com/ralovely/simple_hashtag/blob/master/lib/simple_hashtag/hashtaggable.rb#L21), but to make it used by my app, I need also to include the callback

```
before_save :update_hashtags
```

I have an [initializer](https://gist.github.com/schatteleyn/d9228404170fbff44cac) that I first used to act the multitenancy system to hashtags (so the tenant_id is automatically saved). I added the methods, but when trying to override the callback, I hit a wall.

If I use the extend ActiveSupport::Concern like in the gist, I get this error and can't start my app.

```
lib/active_support/concern.rb:126:in `included': Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern (ActiveSupport::Concern::MultipleIncludedBlocks)
        from /Users/schatteleyn/subarashi/config/initializers/hashtags.rb:16:in `<module:Hashtaggable>'
        from /Users/schatteleyn/subarashi/config/initializers/hashtags.rb:14:in `<module:SimpleHashtag>'
        from /Users/schatteleyn/subarashi/config/initializers/hashtags.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

And if I use the version with

```
def self.included(base)
  base.class_eval do
    before_save :do_something
  end
end
```

I get this error, and can start my app, but get the error on any page.

```
undefined method `before_save' for HashtagConcern:Module
```

I'm at a loss, those are the only two solutions I can find, and I can't seem to make them works. 
Is there any other way to use the callback in a module ? Or maybe another way to solve the problem of finding by name and tenant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the simple_hashtag be tenant-aware, just override the validation of the Hashtag model, for example like this:

```
SimpleHashtag::Hashtag.clear_validators!
module SimpleHashtag
  class Hashtag < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_tenant :tenant
    validates :name, :uniqueness => { :scope => :tenant }
  end
end
```